# Parsing through model for checked checkboxes in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

can someone provide me with a good example of a controller to process checked checkboxes for a model?

eg. How would I in the controller grab only the checked items as well as their corresponding drop down box value?

The View

```
 <form>
      <table>
           <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="something" value="12345" checked="true" />
                    <select>
                         <option value="1">1</option>
                         <option value="2">2</option>
                         <option value="3">3</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
                <td>
                     <input type="checkbox" name="something" value="54321" checked="false" />
                     <select>
                         <option value="1">1</option>
                         <option value="2">2</option>
                         <option value="3">3</option>
                     </select>
                </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
                <td>
                     <input type="checkbox" name="something" value="11111" checked="false" />
                     <select>
                         <option value="1">1</option>
                         <option value="2">2</option>
                         <option value="3">3</option>
                     </select>
                </td>
           </tr>
      </table>
      <input type="submit" />
 </form>
```

The Model

```
 public class FormCollection 
 {
   // how would this look?
 }
```

The Controller

```
 public ActionResult Sort(FormCollection model)
 {
   FormCollection _model = new FormCollection();
   // iterate through model to get only values that are checked
   // add them to _model
   // how would this look?
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, class `FormCollection` is already exist in the framework: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.formcollection(v=vs.108).aspx so if you want to combine submitted data to a model, use another name for a model class.

Secondly, checkbox list binds on `IEnumerable<string>`, so your action may look as follows:

```
public ActionResult Sort(IEnumerable<string> something)
{
  // iterates only checked items
  foreach(var item in something)
  {
    var correspondingDropdownValue = Request.Form[item]
  }
}
```

This requires to add `name` fields to your dropdowns and make them correspond to checkbox value:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="something" value="11111" checked="false" />
<select name="11111">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks Dima. That was actually really simple. I've updated the code a bit, could you also show me how I would get the corresponding drop down value for the ones that are checked in the controller?

Comment: Have updated answer. Basically, you may refer to `Request.Form` collection to get corresponding dropdowns.